# Why Either value is not discarded?

Tags: haskell, monads

Have the following in *ghci*:

```
:m + Control.Monad.Error
let f x = Right x

Left 1.0 >> Right 1 >>= f
```

gives

```
Left 1.0
```

As I understand >> operator discards monadic result of the first argument,
but I see that here it is preserved. Could you please explain?

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.Either.html#Either

strangely, that link doesn't show how Either is implementing methods of Monad typeclass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As I understand[, the] `>>` operator discards monadic result of the first argument,

No, it does **not**. It more or less sees `Left` like a `Maybe` monad sees `Nothing` (the main difference is that `Left` also carries a value). Therefore it is sometimes used as an "advanced `Maybe`" that can for instance carry error messages.

`(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b` is a function such that **`f >> g` is equivalent to `f >>= \_ -> g`** and `f >>= const g`. This is the default implementation in the `Monad` typeclass.

It depends thus on how `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` is implemented.

Now for an `Either` it is [implemented as](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.Either.html#line-141):

> ```
> instance Monad (Either e) where
>     Left  l >>= _ = Left l
>     Right r >>= k = k r
> ```

So that means in case of a **`Left l` on the left hand side, then the right hand side is ignored**, in case the left hand side is a `Right r`, then `k` is applied to the value the `Right` constructor is wrapping.

So we can replace your query with (added brackets for clarity):

```
   Left 1.0 >> Right 1 >>= f
=  (>>) (Left 1.0) (Right 1 >>= f)
-> Left 1.0
```

Semantically you can see an `Either` as a "more advanced" version of `Maybe` where `Left` takes the place of the `Nothing`. So from the moment someting is `Left x`, then it stays `Left x`. Regardless how we bind it.

Comment: I think it would help address the confusion in the question if you explain how `a >> b` is different from an operator like `f a b = b`, which is often what people think when they see that `>>` discards the value on its left hand. The difference, of course, is that `>>` discards the monadic *value*, but not the monadic *context`.

Comment: @Willem, does (>>) (Left 1.0)(Right 1 >>= f) equal to (Left 1.0) >> (Right 1 >>= f) so that according to (Left  l >>= _ = Left l) (Right 1 is discarded)? If so, it is understandable. Initially, I thought that the priority was  (Left 1.0 >> Right 1) >>= f

Comment: @Willem, also: does Either inherit default >> implementation from Monad?
I didn't find explicit implementation of >> in Either.

Comment: @BulatM.: you are correct `(>>=)` (and `(>>)`) binds right to left. And indeed `class Monad` has a default implementation `a >> b = a >> \_ -> b`, so if you do not specify it in the `instance`, then the default is used.

Answer (score 2):

Notice the definition contradicts your belief about discarding the left value of a sequence operator:

```
instance Monad (Either e) where
    Left  l >>= _ = Left l
    Right r >>= k = k r
```

In fact, in the case of `Left` the `Right` value is discarded.

See the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.Either.html#line-136) which can be found by clicking on the `Monad` instance under the `Either` declaration in the haddocks.

Answer (score 2):

The "result" which is being discarded refers only to the `a` values contained in (not always literally) an `m a` value, not the rest of it. In case of `Either` it means that the value of a `Right` will be ignored, but not whether it's `Left` or `Right`, or the value of a `Left`.

If you combine the definition of `>>=` for `Either` and the default definition of `>>`, you'll see that `>>` here is effectively

```
Left  l >> x = Left  l >>= \_ -> x = Left l
Right r >> x = Right r >>= \_ -> x = x
```

and the result in the second clause indeed doesn't depend on `r`.